# Add amount of gold to player

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm new here , I hope I can learn and share knowledge .

Good This is my first post , and it is one with doubts.

I have a [ Mu Online] server Ex 802, and the same features of { } SHOP CASH system for players to buy your items. Well my server has a control panel on which I can add the amount of money that the player will have , the more this system is in C#.

The Cash Shop game uses one table to connect with sql :

```
     - Table " GameShop_Data"
     - Columns " MemberGuid , WCoinC , WCoinP , WCoinG"
```

It does this check : When you enter the game, and opens the Shop Cash , there is a field called : { Golds number: VALUE }

Basically checking that golds qts has it does the following : IT SEARCH TABLE SQL to " GameShop_Data " (as the user connected with his account he already is based on member_guid ) so he table scan the connected user MemberGuid field and it has the " WCoinC " column ( being the main currency ) and see the amount of Golds in this column and shows it in GAME the amount found in SQL.

- The columns beginning with W are the types of currency that has the SET.
- The MemberGuid column is like a kind of " id" organization.

However the server has a site in which there are 3 types of control panel:

- User Control Panel
- Game Master Control Panel
- Administrator Control Panel
- On the control panel { } administrator has the option to add the quantity of money , it exists two types of currencies.
- To add basically need three fields {login , name of the currency ( SELECT being two ) , number } .

But if I only put the login as identification, will not work.

The simple reason:

```
INSERT INTO "GameShop_Data" ("username","WCoinC", ...) 
VALUES ("user typed in input", "VALUE entered in input",);
```

If you run this code , it will pop up a " id" random in the database .

An example : If the user I want to put gold , has a number of id 25 , more in Table 3 users placed there , i.e. we assume that these three I put the ' Golds ' through the panel I mentioned up there first done in C # .

```
[ MemberGuid ]    |    [ WCoinC ]    |    [WCoinP]    |    [WCoinP]

 "1"                 "500"             "NULL"           "NULL"
 "2"                 "500"             "NULL"           "NULL"
 "3"                 "500"             "NULL"           "NULL"
```

" PANEL BY EXECUTED SCRIPT MADE IN C # IS WORKING PROPERLY"

But if I run the above script with data in specific with a base that user I typed in the input of the WEBSITE Control Panel field the id is "6"

```
INSERT INTO "GameShop_Data" ("username","WCoinC", ...) 
VALUES ("mauricio1", "1000",);  "
```

TABLE SO WOULD STAY :

```
[ MemberGuid ]   |   [ WCoinC ]   |   [WCoinP]   |   [WCoinP]   | [username]

 "1"               "500"           "NULL"          "NULL"       "NULL"
 "2"               "500"           "NULL"          "NULL"       "NULL"
 "3"               "500"           "NULL"          "NULL"       "NULL"
 "4"               "1000"          "NULL"          "NULL"       "mauricio1"
```

In other words, he created a random MemberGuid by itself it is an "int" with primary key ( and not put the id " 6" in the game that would identify the ' Golds ' the logged account) .

Well I would like to know which script I ultilizar to do this check properly and thus be able to add the Golds for players through the Control Panel WEBSITE .

- Remember that the id login each account is on the table " MEMB_INFO " as in the second image of the publication.

I will look for answers.

Images Tables

[ ' GameShop_Data '  ]

[image: GameShop_Data]

[ ' MEMB_INFO '

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVipU.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

What about setting IDENTITY_INSERT to ON?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx